# How does the Lifecycle of DS Components work?

Tags: java, osgi, bnd

In which order are the annotated methods called on bundle start and stop?

I use the annotations of aQute.bnd.annotation.

Is there any documentation on this?

My guess is that it is:
on bundle start:

1. SetA
2. onStartUp (@Activate)

on bundle stop:

1. unsetA
2. onShutdown (@Deactivate)

I need a method which is called after all Service-references to the component are unset. Can I use the @Deactivate method for this?

```
@Component(immediate=true)
public class AImpl implements A {

    @Activate
    public void onStartUp() {

    }

    @Deactivate
    public void onShutDown() {

    }

}


public class B {


private A a;

@Reference(name = "a", 
    service = A.class,  
    optional = false,
    multiple = false,
    dynamic = true,
    unbind = "unsetA")
    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void unsetA(A a) {
        this.a = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifecycle is specified in the "Declarative Services" chapter of OSGi compendium specification. Although you use annotations, an XML is generated and DS works based on the XML.

In case the component is stopped, @Deactivate method is called before the references are unset. You use dynamic reference so it might happen that your reference is unset before stopping the component.

Based on your sample, you can achieve your goal in the following way:

```
public class B {

    private boolean started;

    private AtomicReference<A> a = new AtomicReference<A>();

    @Reference(name = "a", 
        service = A.class,  
        optional = false,
        multiple = false,
        dynamic = true,
        unbind = "unsetA")
    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a.set(a) = a;
    }

    public void unsetA(A a) {
        this.a.set(null);
        if (!started) {
            componentIsStoppedAndReferencesAreUnset();
        }
    }

    @Activate
    public void activate() {
        started = true;
    }

    @Deactivate
    public void deactivate() {
        started = false;
        if (this.a.get() == null) {
            componentIsStoppedAndReferencesAreUnset();
        }
    }

    public void componentIsStoppedAndReferencesAreUnset() {
        // Implement your logic here
    }
}
```

If you had more references, you should check all of them for null in all of the unset methods and in the deactivate one. If you had static reference as well, you could skip the check in the deactivate method as it would be sure that the static reference would be unset after the deactivate method.

Please note that if you use dynamic reference, you should use AtomicReference as your member variable for thread safety.